# Custom Facebook CSS (Stylish)

Tags: css, facebook, firefox, stylish

I'm creating a custom style for Facebook with the Firefox plugin *Stylish*. I'm trying to get the top blue bar flat, but I cannot. I use the CSS code:

```
#blueBar {
   background-color: transparent !important;
    }
```

But it has no affect on it. Why is this?

Comment: I just did a quick inspect element on facebook, they have a few different style sheets with background colors but they are also adding a background image. get ride of the image and try it again

Answer (score 1):

@BrockAdams - I tried that, still nothing so I just used:

```
#blueBar {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/vUnrU8x.png") !important;
    }
```

Comment: My mistake.  I misinterpreted what you meant by "flat".

Answer (score 0):

Try to use change id #blueBarHolder background. like:

```
.hasSmurfbar #blueBarHolder, .hasSmurfbar #blueBarHolder.slim, 
.hasSmurfbar #blueBarHolder #pageHead, 
.hasSmurfbar #blueBarHolder #headNav, 
.hasSmurfbar #blueBarHolder #blueBar {
         background: transparent !important;
}
```

Hope it will works.

Comment: It just turned it white...
Though it does work for this theme, which is beyond me on why it does.
http://userstyles.org/styles/66528/facebook-flat-massive#view-code

EDIT: I actually tried the theme and it did not work, it appears Facebook changed something...